# Adding a count process to a function

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I need to tally up the values of a variable used in a function.. I can't run a simple `$count++` because the value of that variable rarely equals 1.

```
Function Set-bhRTGmembers_logonly {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    $DirectReports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object -expand samAccountName
    #  Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        $script:LogOnlyAddUserCount++
        $LogLine = "Report to $Manager would be updated with $DirectReports"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
    else {
        $LogLine = "Group for $Manager not found, would be updated with $DirectReports"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogOnlyFile -LineValue $LogLine 
    }
}
```

Line 7 is trying to count the number of SamAccountNames in $DirectReports, how can I do this?

Comment: `$DirectReports.Count` contains the count if it is a collection. `($DirectReports | Measure-Object).Count` works even if there is not a collection

Comment: What is the purpose of using a script variable for the count? How are you using it? Functions having side effect is typically bad practice.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Nice.. so that should get a number per iteration, how can I add those all up? Maybe a $script:LogOnlyAddUserCount = ($DirectReports | Measure-Object).count ?

Comment: Actually no, that did not work. Toss your comment in as a solution, also your thoughts on how to add all of the .Count interations up into a summary value please.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on what you're asking for

Comment: Eh I should probably throw that in as a separate question.  @AdminOfThings I need a solution from you bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the number of items contained in `$DirectReports`, you can simply use its alias property `Count` (if it is a collection) or [Measure-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.1). `Measure-Object` works no matter the number of items contained within `$DirectReports`.

```
($DirectReports | Measure-Object).Count
```